# Prevent Cora Data Insertions

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Is there any way to get notified when an `NSManagedObjectContext` is **about to** insert an object, and then prevent this? Maybe a method like `-shouldInsertObject:` or something.

I am creating a lite version of my app and want a certain entity to have a maximum of three objects. Instead of going over my code and adding an `if` wherever I create a new instance of that entity, I would like to prevent this in one place.

I looked at the `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` and `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` notifications but they are both not suitable. When these notifications are posted, objects have already been added.

Comment: I think you will need yourself to monitor when insert is being called, because until insert is called how would system will know that on the next line it will be having some insertion of entity?

Comment: @Ravin How would you monitor when `insert` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could leverage that Core Data does not store the Entity to the Store when you insert, this only happens when you save the context. So in the method where you save the context, you can build a fetchRequest and get the number of entities already in the store:

```
- (NSUInteger)countForFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request error:(NSError **)error
```

If this is three or more, simply get the objects not yet saved using:

```
- (NSSet *)insertedObjects
```

which is a set containing the objects inserted but not yet persisted to the store, and delete these. (warn the user, ask them to buy the full version etc.)

Comment: Great idea, I am going to try this out now!

Comment: Cool:), I just wanted to add something. I think it is important that you delete the objects from the context and then remember to carry out the saving of the context afterwards (not just abort the save if there is more than three). If some of your three valid objects has been changed they should be persisted, which is ok to do after you deleted the insertedObjects.